# Ignore after n-th delimiter of a split_part

Tags: postgresql

I have a text like this:

```
'a:b:c:d'
```

I would like to ignore the last part of the split text, my result should be

```
'a:b:c'
```

I tried `split_part` on it, but it doesn't work, neither applying reverse at it.

Queries I tried and didn't worked:

```
select split_part('a:b:c:d', ':', 1);

select reverse(split_part(reverse('a:b:c:d'), ':', -1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) with a regular expression: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ktJe3UdF)

```sql
select substring('a:b:c:d' FROM '^(([^:]*:){2}[^:]*)');--first 3 groups
select substring('a:b:c:d' FROM '^(.*):[^:]*');--all but the last group
```

Which is looking for two sets of non-colon characters that end with a colon, then then one such set after that. It uses [POSIX syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

- `^` at the beginning, outside square brackets, means you start at the beginning
- `[^:]` means any character except a colon
- `.` means any character, at all
- `*` means any amount of the previous thing
- `[^:]*` means any amount of that anything, except a colon
- `[^:]*:` means the same, followed by an actual colon
- `([^:]*:){2}` means the same, just repeated twice

Since PostgreSQL arrays support [subscripts and slices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING), you can also [split the text into an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTION-STRING-TO-ARRAY), use a `[:3]` to get your first 3 elements, then [reassemble](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#FUNCTION-ARRAY-TO-STRING) the text:

```sql
--first 3 groups
select array_to_string((string_to_array('a:b:c:d',':'))[:3],':');
--all but the last group
select reverse(array_to_string((string_to_array(reverse('a:b:c:d'),':'))[2:],':'));
```

You can also do it your own way:

```sql
select reverse( substring( reverse('a:b:c:d') 
                           from 
                           1+position(':' in reverse('a:b:c:d') )
                          )
               );--all but the last group
```

This spots the position of the first colon in reversed version of the text, saves only what comes after that first colon, then reverses it back again.

Comment: the first is a  bad choice like every regex you need fixed pattern,but when you add some additional :: you get the wrong answer only the second like mine works https://dbfiddle.uk/ot1B-srL and your second also https://dbfiddle.uk/rsIOoPKm

Comment: @nbk Thanks for the remarks. I realised I went for the "first N" approach suggested by the title, assuming the "all but last" is OP's other way of restating the same. I added the "all but last" versions after seeing JohnH's answer pointing out the two approaches are not equivalent and it's better to offer a solution for each but it seems like your comment was faster than my edit. Your solution works just fine, except for the trailing colon caused by the `+1` - OP's *"my result should be"* example omits it.

Comment: It worked perfectly, and will help me on future demands, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` and find the last : in the string

```
SELECT substring('a:b:c:d' from 1 for length('a:b:c:d') - position(':' in reverse('a:b:c:d')) + 1 )
```

| substring |
| --- |
| a:b:c: |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ELhVQUvf)

Answer (score 0):

With only one example, your goal is ambiguous. The following query demonstrates approaches using regular expressions to keep only the portion with the first `n` fields, or all but the last field:

```
WITH t(test_string) AS (
  VALUES ('a:b:c:d'), ('a:b:c:d:e'))
SELECT t.test_string,
       s.n,
       regexp_replace(t.test_string, FORMAT('^((([^:]*):){%s}[^:]*).*$', s.n - 1),'\1') AS first_n,
       regexp_replace(t.test_string, '^(.*):[^:]*$', '\1') AS exclude_last
  FROM t
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 4) s(n)
  ORDER BY t.test_string, s.n;
```

Running this query produces the following output:

| test_string | n | first_n | exclude_last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a:b:c:d | 1 | a | a:b:c |
| a:b:c:d | 2 | a:b | a:b:c |
| a:b:c:d | 3 | a:b:c | a:b:c |
| a:b:c:d | 4 | a:b:c:d | a:b:c |
| a:b:c:d:e | 1 | a | a:b:c:d |
| a:b:c:d:e | 2 | a:b | a:b:c:d |
| a:b:c:d:e | 3 | a:b:c | a:b:c:d |
| a:b:c:d:e | 4 | a:b:c:d | a:b:c:d |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL query below to ignore the final character of a text string in PostgreSQL, such as changing 'a:b:c:d' into 'a:b:c'. This command basically removes the last section of the text by extracting a substring from the original string .

```
SELECT substring('a:b:c:d' FROM 1 FOR strpos('a:b:c:d', ':' FROM length('a:b:c:d') - 1));
```